# Add language detection to `_default` in Solr

Tags: solr, schema, language-detection

I'm working on Solr 7.3 and I have an "indexing job" which is a black box (can't look at inside). The output of the "indexing job" with `_default` config is this:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":31,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*"}},
  "response":{"numFound":18,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Hin1",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Hin1",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Hin1",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[3220],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340155838496768,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Hin2",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Hin2",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Hin2",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[2649],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340160634683392,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:56 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Ar2",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Ar2",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Ar2",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[2649],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340160124026880,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:47 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Rus2",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Rus2",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Rus2",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[852],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340160584351744,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:52 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Ar1",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Ar1",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Ar1",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[2678],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340155296382976,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:49 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Sp1",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Sp1",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Sp1",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[320],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340159144656896,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:48 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Ger2",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Ger2",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Ger2",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[626],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340161147437056,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:53 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Rus1",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Rus1",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Rus1",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[715],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340156644851712,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Fr1",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Fr1",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Fr1",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[1211],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340158946476032,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:55 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]},
      {
        "lastaccesstime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "accessflags":[136],
        "id":"/ifs/language/Beng2",
        "readable_to":"S-1-22-1-0",
        "objecttype":["file"],
        "path":"/ifslanguage/Beng2",
        "fileattributes":[128],
        "dacls":"S-1-22-1-0:1442207, S-1-22-2-0:1179785, S-1-1-0:1179785",
        "groupsid":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "ownersid":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "lastwritetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "filename":"Beng2",
        "allocationsize":[1048576],
        "filemode":[0],
        "clustername":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"],
        "changetime":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "clusterip":["172.19.2.140"],
        "stream_size":[2301],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["smb"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "lastwritetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "x_parsed_by_str":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "content_type_str":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "stream_content_type_str":["smb"],
        "objecttype_str":["file"],
        "lastaccesstime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "_version_":1608340161101299712,
        "clusterip_str":["172.19.2.140"],
        "groupsid_str":["S-1-22-2-0"],
        "content_encoding_str":["UTF-8"],
        "ownersid_str":["S-1-22-1-0"],
        "changetime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "creationtime_str":["Thu Aug 09 16:37:50 UTC 2018"],
        "clustername_str":["ISL-TEST-8-1-0-0-40"]}]
  }}
```

I added `LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory` class to `_default` to detect language and show it as `language_s` beside other fields:

```
   <updateRequestProcessorChain name="langid">
     <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
       <str name="langid.fl">text_general</str>
       <str name="langid.langField">language_s</str>
       <str name="langid.fallback">generic</str>
       <str name="langid.threshold">0.2</str>
       <bool name="langid.enforceSchema">false</bool>
```

I also added "langid" to `initParams`:

```
  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="df">_text_</str>
       <str name="update.chain">langid</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

All in all, after adding `langid` and running the "indexing job", i get nothing:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":16,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Is there any way to fix this problem without touching the "indexing job"? Am I missing something in config file?

Comment: I can't see any field named `text_general` in the output from your indexing job, neither does any of the field look like usable sources for detecting language from as they don't contain any actual text. Which of the values do you want to detect the language for? (those fields should be the content of `langid.fl`)

Comment: I also tried with `_text_` which is not shown there, but I can see it's tokenized and indexed -it's not stored though! However, there was no luck!

Comment: But are any of the fields shown usable for identifying language? That you're getting no documents indexed at all seems weird - have you confirmed that the Solr log doesn't contain any errors? Do you have required processors at the end of your chain?

Comment: Additionally - copyFields happen _after_ any update chains has run as far as I remember, so there might not be any content for `_text_` when your processor runs.

Comment: I have `LogUpdateProcessorFactory` and `RunUpdateProcessorFactory` processors at the end of the chain, and non of the shown fields are usable for language detection. I'll try if I can get the content copied to `_text_` _before_